# Visualizing multiple dummy variables in a proportional stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have ten dummy variables [Yes/No]. I can't convert them to one categorical variable as people in this survey can tick yes on more than one of these dummies.

I need to represent the percentage of yes answers for all these variables in one stacked bar graph. The below is my attempt but no idea how to even get a single variable represented (keep getting error that x needs to be defnied) not to mention multiple.

I've picked the stacked bar graph idea from https://r-graphics.org/recipe-bar-graph-proportional-stacked-bar

Any help would be appreciated.

```
a <- c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no")
b <- c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes")
c <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")

test <- data.frame(a, b, c)

ggplot(test, aes(y = a)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

https://r-graphics.org/recipe-bar-graph-proportional-stacked-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to reshape the data to long format and to use `geom_bar` instead.
In the code below I will use the pipe operator introduced in R 4.1.0 and a function from package `tidyr` to reshape the data.

```
library(ggplot2)

test |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(a:c) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = name, fill = value)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!